# Processing large zip files in mapreduce using ZipFileInputFormat is failing

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to process bunch of zip files using mapreduce .
My code is working fine and i am able to process all small zip file into HBase .
But when size of the zip files increases more than 30 mb then i am getting

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
```

Exception.
This is the code where it unzip files and loads into memory and then process it .

```
// Read the file contents
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] temp = new byte[8192];
        while ( true )
        {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            try
            {
                bytesRead = zip.read( temp, 0, 8192 );
            }
            catch ( EOFException e )
            {
                if ( ZipFileInputFormat.getLenient() == false )
                    throw e;
                return false;
            }
            if ( bytesRead > 0 )
                bos.write( temp, 0, bytesRead );
            else
                break;
        }
```

I have increased mapred memory also .Below is my configuration file .

```
hbaseConf.set("mapreduce.child.java.opts", "-Xmx6553m");
hbaseConf.set("mapreduce.map.memory.mb", "8192");
```

Any suggestion please .

Comment: Did you do some profiling on a local instance to understand the exact memory requirements of your code?

Comment: I did not get you .Do you mean that for this configuration atleast 50 mb of zip file will not work?

Comment: What I mean is: I have *no* idea how much memory is *really* required in your setup to open/process a 30+ MB zip files. Do you know? Because that number is the one that you need to configure for.